# Like Operator is not returning all matching records when records contains ": and /" character

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using oracle11g, i have a table called **user_records**.

**TableName: user_records**

```
ID  URI
---------- 
1.  Johnmack://*
2.  Capre://Californiya
3.  Johnmack://*/????
4.  Kalmec://duek
```

my query is:-

```
select * from user_records where URI like 'Johnmack://%';
```

when i am executing this query it is returning only one result as

**Query Output:**

```
 1.  Johnmack://*
```

Eventhough i have used like with '%' but still it is using strict pattern matching.

i want this query should return following result:

**Expected Query Output:**

```
1.  Johnmack://*
3.  Johnmack://*/????
```

i want to know that why oracle is doing like this and concept behind this also. 
Thank you,

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08f74/1 there must be something you are not telling us.

Comment: Please use `DUMP()` to verify that your data contains exactly what you think.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in your fiddle the 3rd line of data is not the same as the OP.  If I add the 4 question marks in errors.  weird

Comment: @Fred: yes I know, seems to be a bug in SQLFiddle. This one works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71e4d/1  (but even the first fiddle shows that there must be something else going on)

Comment: I bet SQLFiddle has a broken parser that looks for `?` placeholders. I know because I've written such broken parsers myself.

Comment: Works in my Oracle11g, too. Maybe there is some binary zero or something alike in the second string? See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89687a/5 .

Comment: Thanks to all of you for quick reply and special thanks to @Alvaro G Vicario for providing me the info about dump() by which i am able to resolve my issue, there was a space present in between one of the uri. after removing that space it is working fine.